# Flag duplicate records in a table based on a field value

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I have a table with

```
Name | Type | Area
```

For Type=A I want to store two new fields

Duplicate_Name where another record exists in the table that = or contains that name

Duplicate_Name_Area same as above but only where the Area is the same as well

In an ideal world I'd update not only with flag but with count.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data you want in a `select` query and a self-join:

```
select t.name, t.type, t.area,
       count(*) - 1 as Duplicate_Name,
       sum(tother.area = t.area) - 1 as Duplicate_Name_Area
from table t left outer join
     table tother
     on tother.name like concat('%', t.name, '%');
```

Note the `- 1`.  This is because a given record will always match itself.  You don't seem to have a unique id in the table (tables should always have a unique id), so the query just subtracts `1` from the total number of matches.

Also, the comparison for `name` is not going to perform well on larger data because it cannot take advantage of an index.

Comment: Hi thanks. In fact it is a pretty large table, but I do in fact have an ID Primary Key.  If you mean an index on the specified fields I can add indexes as needed so I'm assuming I should then add an index on the fields involved in the query?

Comment: @MarkH . . . An index will not help, because you are searching for a string within a string.  The only use of the primary key is to remove the `- 1` and include `and tother.pk <> tname.pk` in the `on` clause.